# No output when running function in terminal

Tags: javascript, date, ecmascript-6

Would like some help with my code please. When I run it on my terminal there is no output. I am trying to print the day of the dateString I am passing into the function. For example, if I pass in todays date which is 02/05/2019 it should print a Tuesday.

I have tried calling the function on a separate line and using console.log to print it maybe that would have worked but it didn't.

```js
var dateString = ('10/16/2012');
const getDayName = (date) =>   {
  var days =  new Date(dateString);
  const weekDays = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saurday'];
  return weekDays[days.getDay()];
};

console.log(getDayName);
```

Comment: You just need to call the function: `console.log( getDayName() )`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function can be reduced to:

```js
function getDayName(s) {
  return ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'][new Date(s).getDay()];
}

console.log(getDayName('10/16/2012'));
```

Or if you really must to use a function expression:

```js
let getDayName = s => ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'][new Date(s).getDay()];

console.log(getDayName('10/16/2012'));
```

In less code and supporting the host default language:

```js
let getDayName = s => new Date(s).toLocaleString(void 0, {weekday:'long'});

console.log(getDayName('10/16/2012'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple errors/inconsistencies in your code.

- You are logging the function itself and not calling it.
- You don't use the date argument in your function, you directly access the global variable.

Here is a corrected version:

```js
const getDayName = dateString => {
  const date = new Date(dateString);
  const weekDays = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saurday'];
  return weekDays[date.getDay()];
};

console.log(getDayName('10/16/2012'));
```